# How to structure tests cleanly in PhpUnit

Tags: php, ruby, rspec, phpunit

I'm new to PhP and coming from a Ruby background. In Ruby we could structure tests using `context` blocks very cleanly.

For example -

```
describe "CheckoutService"
    context "with a user who has a card" do
        let(user) { mock_user }
        let(card) { mock_valid_card }
        before do
            user.card = card
            user.save()
            // more related complicated setup could go here
        end

        context "with valid card" do
            it "checks out smoothly" do
                user.checkout()
                assert_success()
            end
        end

        context "with invalid card" do
            let(card) { mock_invalid_card}

            it "throws error" do
                user.checkout()
                assert_failure()
            end
        end
        
    end

    context "with a user who doesn't have a card" do
        it "redirects to add card" do
            user.checkout()
            assert_redirect()
        end
    end
end
```

Here, each `context` can have its own `before` and `after` block where I can setup the specific tests cleanly and without much repetition.

Is there such a thing in PhpUnit?

PS - I feel this is different from DataProviders that PhPUnit provides. They seem to repeat the same test but for different parameters, whereas using `context` we have more freedom around the setup of the test. Additionally the test is much more readable

Comment: Most likely those ain't unit tests you outline as Ruby code, however the first level of grouping in Phpunit is the test-case class. You also have setUp and tearDown (also per class), therefore you can create a Fixture to that test-case which could be the context in your example. See _Fixtures_ and compare with _Test Dependencies_.

Comment: @hakre is right those are not really unit tests. You maybe conflating Behavior Driven Development and Test Driven Development to some extent. Either way  check out https://github.com/danielstjules/pho it claims to be a *"BDD test framework for PHP, inspired by Jasmine and RSpec"* and the examples seem to align with that (although I don't write PHP at all)